# Building a dataframe from a nested dictionary of dataframes

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a nested dictionary `my_dfs` of dataframes, e.g.:

```
my_dfs[depth_1][depth_2] = pd.DataFrame(...)
```

I would like to convert this to a Multi-Index Dataframe so that `depth_1` and `depth_2` are encoded as **levels** of the **columns**, and the **rows are padded** with **NaNs** to the size of the DataFrame with the highest number of rows. How can I do that?

Comment: What do you want to happen when they have different columns?  Do you want to get columns full of `nan`?

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn. If the final dataframe is multi-index, I don't think  we need to make sure that the number of columns is consistent across different entries within the same level.

Comment: I don't get what you mean.  If you combine them into one DataFrame, it has to have one set of columns.  If some of the sub-dataframes you're using to build it don't have values for that column, you have to decide what to put in for those columns at that position.

Comment: @BrenBarn See the examples [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object). If `depth_1` is used, for example, to multi-index rows, and `depth_2` to multi-index columns, there won't be any rows or columns to fill-in.

Comment: But then what happens to the rows and columns of the individual dataframes?  Are you saying you want each element of the big DataFrame to be another DataFrame?  It might be best if you edit your question to give a simple example of what input/ouput you want.

Comment: Thanks @BrenBarn I see what you mean. You are right. I have updated the OP.

Comment: It's still not clear from that edit how you want the data from the original DataFrames to be reshaped.  Can you provide a simple example?